# Letting google know about my Mobile template

Tags: php, mobile, smarty

How do I let google know I have a mobile template available for my site, Im pretty sure Im using ALT CSS, but the site is a script and I can not install it on a subomain, like m.mydomain.co.za - I created the subdomain, but redirect it to the mobile template at www.mydomainmydomain.co.za?template=mobile

And the desktop site I direct to www.mydomainmydomain.co.za?template=browser

How do I let google know mobile is a mobile template?

Thanks Sarah

Comment: why would you let google know about your template?

Comment: Because I need google to pick up that I've got a template for mobile phones, when you search on mobile then and see our result, youll get a small phone icon next to your result which means you have a mobi site

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: I only want to write one set of pages on my site for whatever device, so I put this in ... It relies on the screen size of the device and will switch in the appropriate CSS as required.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/android.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/default.css" media="screen and (min-width: 481px)" />
```

Another thing to look at would be detecting the device type using this PHP code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) ) { // its a mobile! }
```